Correct way to use gorm.Order() with placeholders
I need to use Order with placeholders, e.g tx.Order("CASE WHEN Field1 = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END", FieldValue)
This is supported by MySQL, but not by gorm. So I tried to use raw sql method as well, but there no way to escape the values, otherwise I'm facing sql injection issue.
What's the best practice in this situation?

Manually validate FieldValue content before running the query, as mentionned in the documentation: you can perform whitelist validation to test user input against an existing set of known, approved, and defined input
